# Blender 3.1 IK Bones Snap Out of Position When Moving Them

Tags: armature, bones, transforms, inverse-kinematics

This seems more like a bug then anything else, but maybe I'm overlooking something.

I have this coat that I've rigged that has worked just fine in the past, but now it's doing this weird thing where when I move one of the IKed bone chains, it snaps away from where I move it.  Here's a clip, but all I'm doing is pressing  <kbd>G</kbd>, moving it, then left clicking:

[Coat Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LELKf.jpg)

Any ideas as to how this could be happening?  Like I said, I've never seen this before, and this same armature has worked just fine in the past.

https://pasteall.org/blend/ad5e20e1228d499fa7291b82bab04118

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: I originally tried to post a GIF or an MP4, but the tools wouldn't let me, so I used the link.  Not the easiest way to do it, but that's what worked.

Comment: It looks like it has to do with the bone called Chest Main that is both parented to Main and that also has a Child Of constraint with the target bone called j_sebo_c of the armature called n_root, a bit too complicated for me  :/  Also maybe you should apply the scale of your armature

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I had to apply the mesh's *AND* the armature's scale while they were both in the rest position.  I also had to make sure all of the child of constraints were disabled while doing so, and then reset the inverse on each by setting the influence to 0, clear inverse, set inverse, then set the influence to 1.  It works now!  I didn't even consider that I scaled the armature and not just the mesh.  Still in the Blender learning process :).  Thanks for the suggestions moonboots!  You saved me again.